# Latest update broke Wi-Fi

Tags: wireless, internet

I got the latest update for Ubuntu Studio 19.04, and now I have to boot *then restart* to access Wi-Fi. I can't get any Wi-Fion the initial boot.

How can I fix this issue? I'm relatively new to Ubuntu.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `dkms status` and `sudo lshw -C network` (when connected via wireless). Does wireless connect, but no Internet access... or not even connect at all?